ORDER column by numeric order not alphabet
i am stuck with an exercise. using WideWorldImporters DataBase
I need to show my results this way:

but no matter what I do in order to get to this exact solution I can't,
because the month column is alphanumeric and not numeric.
the closest I got is this code
I would like some insights in order to solve this problem.
thanks all!!
WITH T1
AS
(
SELECT 
     YEAR(o.OrderDate) AS OrderYear
    ,MONTH(o.OrderDate) AS OrderMonth
    ,SUM(ol.PickedQuantity*ol.UnitPrice) AS MonthlyTotal
    --,SUM(SUM(ol.PickedQuantity*ol.UnitPrice))OVER(PARTITION BY YEAR(o.OrderDate) ORDER BY MONTH(o.OrderDate)) AS CumulativeTotal
    FROM Sales.OrderLines ol
JOIN Sales.Orders o
    ON o.OrderID = ol.OrderID
GROUP BY YEAR(o.OrderDate),YEAR(o.OrderDate),MONTH(o.OrderDate)

)
    SELECT 
         OrderYear
        ,CAST(OrderMonth AS VARCHAR) AS OrderMonth
        ,FORMAT(MonthlyTotal,'#,#.00') AS MonthlyTotal
        ,FORMAT(SUM(MonthlyTotal)OVER(PARTITION BY OrderYear ORDER BY OrderMonth), '#,#.00') AS CumulativeTotal
        FROM t1

UNION ALL

    SELECT 
         t1.OrderYear
        ,'Grand Total' AS OrderMonth
        ,FORMAT(SUM(MonthlyTotal)OVER(PARTITION BY OrderYear ORDER BY OrderMonth), '#,#.00') AS MonthlyTotal
        ,FORMAT(SUM(MonthlyTotal)OVER(PARTITION BY OrderYear ORDER BY OrderMonth), '#,#.00') AS CumulativeTotal
        FROM t1
WHERE (t1.OrderYear = 2013 and OrderMonth = 12)
   OR (t1.OrderYear = 2014 and OrderMonth = 12)
   OR (t1.OrderYear = 2015 and OrderMonth = 12)
   OR (t1.OrderYear = 2016 and OrderMonth = 5)

ORDER BY OrderYear


ROLLUP or GROUPING SETS is what you're looking for. Then just cast the Month column to varchar so you can add the Grand Total label.
You can use the GROUPING function to determine if you are in a rollup row for a given column.
SELECT 
    YEAR(o.OrderDate) AS OrderYear,
    IIF(GROUPING(MONTH(o.OrderDate)) = 0,
        CAST(MONTH(o.OrderDate) AS varchar(10)),
        'Grand Total'
    ) AS OrderMonth,
    SUM(ol.PickedQuantity * ol.UnitPrice) AS MonthlyTotal,
    SUM(SUM(ol.PickedQuantity * ol.UnitPrice)) OVER (
       PARTITION BY YEAR(o.OrderDate), GROUPING(MONTH(o.OrderDate))
       ORDER BY MONTH(o.OrderDate) ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS CumulativeTotal
FROM Sales.OrderLines ol
JOIN Sales.Orders o
    ON o.OrderID = ol.OrderID
WHERE o.OrderDate >= '20130101'
  AND o.OrderDate <  '20160601'
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS (
    (YEAR(o.OrderDate), MONTH(o.OrderDate)),
    (YEAR(o.OrderDate))
)
-- you can also use
-- GROUP BY YEAR(o.OrderDate), ROLLUP(MONTH(o.OrderDate))
ORDER BY
    OrderYear,
    GROUPING(MONTH(o.OrderDate)),
    MONTH(o.OrderDate);

I would strongly recommend you don't use FORMAT if you don't have to, as it's a really slow function.
